# Mocking InputStream, InputStreamReader and BufferedReader

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following piece of code :

```
InputStream inputStream = sftpConfig.getSftpChannel().get(fileAbsolutePath);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)))
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

All I want is to mock these lines, and be flexible in `bufferedReader.readLine()`, because I will have several test cases depending on the lines (a case where the file is empty and the line is null, a case where I get only one line, a case where I get several etc.).

Note : I am using `jsch` library for accessing files on FTP servers, so the method `getSftpChannel()` has `ChannelSftp` as return type, and `get(fileAbsolutePath)` has `InputStream`.

I am using `junit 4.12` and `mockito 3.1.0`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier just to instantiate ByteArrayInputStream instance instead of mocking it and filling it with data you need, e.g.

```
var stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello".getBytes());
```

and you can just use that in place of your InputStream.